# Python/PIL: getting the same byte data out of an Image object as it was instantiated with?

Tags: python, image, byte, python-imaging-library

When using PIL, if I have image data in a byte buffer, I can do the followning to create an Image object ...

```
# Assume `bytedata` is a byte buffer that came
# from reading an image file, or perhaps from a
# decoded image file attachment from an email.
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytedata))
```

However, if I do the following, `imagebytes` always ends up being different from `bytedata`. It usually turns out to be much larger than `bytedata` ...

```
imagebytes = im.tobytes()
```

Is there any way to extract the exact, same data from an Image object that I previously utilized to instantiate it?

I know I could use the `save` method to write this data to a temporary file, and then just read that file. However, I want to accomplish this all in memory, without any file IO.

Of course, this is an over-simplified example. I would not normally need to extract the same data that I just used for creating the object. What I'm looking for is a way to extract the same ***format*** of data as I started with, perhaps after having done something like `im.rotate(30)`, so I can then pass that data to other routines that normally manipulate byte data that was directly read from an image file or decoded from and email attachment.

I couldn't get that to work, and so I just did the following as a simplistic test. The `before` and `after` byte arrays always come back significantly different:

```
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(before))
after = im.tobytes()
```

Is there any way I can get the data I'm looking for out of an Image object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tobytes()` returns the *raw image data* and is never going to match what you read originally. If you need that, save it after you've read it. You could even add it to the image object itself...